# System.currentTimeMillis() to int returns negative value

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I am developing an app in which I am adding views dynamically and assigning an unique id using but it is returning negative value:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
view.setId((int)time);
```

So I searched on google and found another solution but however it also doesn't work. It also returns negative value:

```
Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
view.setId(time.intValue());
```

So how can I convert long value returned by `System.currentTimeMills()` to `int` safely?

`System.currentTimeMills()` returns `1505645107314` while converting to `int` returns `-1888413582`.

Comment: That value doesn't fit in int. Use long.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but view.setId() method require int value and unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value will be changed when a large `long` value is casted to `int`. You may want to divided the time by 1000 to get time in seconds, or subtract the value from time of 1 day ago (depending upon the uniqueness you prefer) and use it as the id of the view.

```
view.setId((int)(time/1000)); //this gives unique id for every second.
```

**Edit**
Use following code to get unique id for every millisecond:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
long yesterday = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
int uniqueId = (int) (yesterday - System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Dividing by 1000 works but is it stable?I mean i hope with this code .. No problem will be generated in future like getting negative value?

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani check edited answer for more precise result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. Why do you use time as unique id? Bad approach.

For instance, `2147483648` would be represented as `-2147483648`. For small values, casting is enough:

```
long l = 42;
int i = (int) l;
```

However, a `long` can hold more information than an `int`, so it's not possible to perfectly convert from `long` to `int`, in the general case.

You can use Hash values within integer limit as unique id.

Answer (score 0):

`currentTimeMillis` returns a long, which can sometimes not fit into an int. Therefore, I don't think you should use this as a way to set unique `int` ids for views.

If you want a unique `int` for each of the views you create, try this approach, create a static counter thingy:

```
static int nextViewID = 0;
```

When you create a new view, you just

```
view.setId(nextViewID);
nextViewID++;
```

If you want a *random* unique integer, you can do something like this:

- Create a static `Set`
- Generate a random integer using `java.util.Random`
- Try to add the number to the set
- Keep generating another integer until you successfully added the number to the set

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Casting from a large data type (such as long) to a smaller data type (like int), in some cases, might lead to a change in value. You can devise other means by dividing by a certain preset constant (say 10,000). For example:

```
Long t = System.currentTimeMillis() / 10000;
view.setId((int) t);
```

This would surely give you a positive value!